# Replit repl not loading

Tags: replit

A repl on [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit) is stuck on loading.

I tried to code my website on Replit, but my repl doesn't load.
It just displays the Replit logo.
I can't send a screenshot from the computer now, but I can send it from the Replit mobile app on an Android phone.

[Loading on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXPf5.jpg)

Comment: That would be a question for Replit support, not SO.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug as per me. It happened to me a lot. There isn't any need to worry. Open the repl the next day and it will work normally.

If the problem exists, then log out from the replit. Also delete the cache of the browser and the next day open it. It should work. One day it happened to me that for three days straight the repl was not opening, so I suggest you to have patience.